# linux appending text gives command not found

Tags: linux, bash

When I try this simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#append csv

FILES= /home/stef/test/*

for f in $FILES do
        cat $f >> ~/test.txt done
```

I get following error:

```
./append.sh: line 4: /home/stef/test/test2.txt: Permission denied.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have read permission of `/home/stef/test/test2.txt`? It looks like you don't.

Comment: directory: drwxr-xr-x
-rw-rw-rw- file

Comment: You apparently do not have read permissions for `/home/stef/test/test2.txt`.

Comment: It's not just the directory permissions that matter, but the file itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

`FILES= /home/stef/test/*`

with

`FILES=/home/stef/test/*`

The script is trying to evaluate the first match of /home/stef/test/*. It says permission denied because the file is not executable.

`./append.sh: line 4: /home/stef/test/test2.txt: Permission denied.`

That's line 4. Try with `FOO= *` in a non-empty directory.

And your `for ... do; done` syntax is borked as well, `done` needs a separator (`;` or newline) and so does "`do`". That's not what produces this erroe message however.

Comment: @sapht it looks like mistake made by editor not author. Main question in antoher.

Comment: No, bash is picky about whitespace in variable assignments, which causes this issue.

Comment: @sehe My tests suggest that it ignores the variable assigment and tries to evaluate the expanded wildcard. In a dir with the file "bar" it would try to execute "bar" from the bin path. I've never seen whitespace after = in production code and consider it an syntax pitfall.

Comment: @sapht: you can prefix simple commands with variable assignments to effect changes to that commnands environments. `FOO= cmd` simply runs `cmd` with `FOO` set to the empty string in its environment; `FOO` in the current environment is left unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this changes in your code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#append csv

FILES=/some_path/*

for f in $FILES
do
        cat $f >> ~/test.txt
done
```

Don't forget to remove whitepsace before path in FILE line,

Answer (score 0):

Missing statement delimiter: Fix it either like

```
for f in $FILES do
        cat $f >> ~/test.txt 
done
```

Or

```
for f in $FILES do
        cat $f >> ~/test.txt; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if any of your filenames have whitespace, you will have problems. When you iterate over a variable with `for`, you are iterating over the whitespace-separated *words* in that variable. To safely iterate over files, regardless whether they have spaces in the names, don't store the list of files in a plain variable.

Most straight-forward way:

```
for f in /home/stef/test/*; do
  # ...
```

If you want to hold the filenames in some kind of container, you need to use an array:

```
files=( /home/stef/test/* )
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  # ...
```