# bash: appending to list fails with "not found"

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have the following script

```
list=\(\)
val=123
list+=\(\"$val\"\)
```

When I copy-paste it to the terminal it works fine, but when I try to run it from inside a `.sh` file, I get this error:

> file.sh: 9: file.sh: list+=("123"): not found

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422369/linux-appending-text-gives-command-not-found) answer here, but it doesn't seem applicable since I'm not using a space.

**btw**, I use `\` in front of `(` because otherwise I get `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`, this also happend only when running from a script file.

What causes the error?

I'm working on GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: The error occurs because you're not using bash.

Comment: The `\(` also stops the `(` from being syntactically meaningful (ie. from telling the parser that it's an array being managed). Using a slash tells the shell **not** to treat something as syntax. Of course, that doesn't help when you're running your script with `/bin/sh`, which (1) is not bash, and (2) doesn't have arrays at all.

Comment: ...incidentally, this is one of the (more minor) reasons why using `.sh` extensions for bash scripts is a bad idea: It falsely implies that they can be run with `sh`, or use a `#!/bin/sh` shebang. Scripts with shebangs and the `+x` bit are executables, and executables shouldn't have extensions; you don't run `ls.elf`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks! Write it as an answer and I'll accept it, if you want

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning the literal string `()` to `list`, not implicitly declaring it as an empty array.

```
list=()
val=123
list+=("$val")
```